# JPA Circular dependency on same entity resulting in recursive output

Tags: json, jpa, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data

I am having a Folder class which in-turn can have many sub-folders. In this case i am trying to make use of same entity that single entity is being used to achieve the same.

Something like below.

```
Folders
----SubFolder
----SubFolder
```

Below are the classes.

**FolderData.java**

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,property="projectId") 
public class FolderData {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq-gen", initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "seq-gen")
    private Integer parentId;

    private int moduleId;

    private int subProjectId;

    private String folderName;

    private Integer folderId;

    private int projectId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="folder_child")
    @JsonIgnore
    private FolderData folderData;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "folderData")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("folderList")
    private Set<FolderData> folderList=new HashSet<>();
}
```

**FodlerController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/folder")
public class FodlerController {

    @Autowired
    private FolderService folderService;

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public List<FolderData> getFolderList(){
        return folderService.findAllFromTheList();
    }


    @PostMapping(produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public void createFolder(@RequestBody FolderData folderData) {
        if(folderData.getId()==null && folderData.getFolderId()==null) {
            System.out.println("id is null");
            folderData.setFolderId(new Random().nextInt());
            folderService.save(folderData);
        }
        else {
            folderService.doChildAddition(folderData);
        }
    }
}
```

**FolderService.java**

```
@Service
public class FolderService {

    @Autowired
    private FolderRepo folderRepo;

    public FolderData save(FolderData folderData) {
        return folderRepo.save(folderData);
    }

    public FolderData getFolderDataByParentId(Integer id) {
        return folderRepo.getOne(id);
    }

    public List<FolderData> findAllFromTheList() {
        return folderRepo.findAll();
    }

    public FolderData getFolderDataByfolderId(Integer folderId) {
        return folderRepo.findFolderByFolderId(folderId);
    }

    public void doChildAddition(FolderData childFolder) {
        FolderData parentFolder=folderRepo.findFolderByFolderId(childFolder.getFolderId());
        childFolder.setFolderData(parentFolder);
        FolderData childFolderSaved = folderRepo.saveAndFlush(childFolder);
        //parentFolder.getFolderList().add(folderRepo.getOne(childFolderSaved.getId()));
        //folderRepo.save(parentFolder);
    }
}
```

Json Request for creating parent and the response collected which includes autogenerated folder id:

```
{
    "moduleId":1,
    "subProjectId":1,
    "folderName":"One",
    "projectId":1
}

[
  {
    "projectId": 0,
    "moduleId": 1,
    "subProjectId": 1,
    "folderName": "One",
    "folderId": 963031296,
    "folderList": [],
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

Creating child for the parent and the response collected.

```
{
    "moduleId":1,
    "subProjectId":2,
    "folderName":"Two",
    "projectId":1,
     "folderId": -963031296
}

[
        {
            "projectId": 0,
            "moduleId": 1,
            "subProjectId": 1,
            "folderName": "One",
            "folderId": 963031296,
            "folderList": [
                {
                    "projectId": 0,
                    "moduleId": 1,
                    "subProjectId": 2,
                    "folderName": "Two",
                    "folderId": 963031296,
                    "id": 2
                }
            ],
            "id": 1
        },
        2
    ]
```

For the above response i am getting the No 2 with the response since i am using

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,property="parentId")
```

else the whole object would have come instead of 2.

Example output had i not used JsonIdentityInfo

```
[
    {
        "projectId": 0,
        "moduleId": 1,
        "subProjectId": 1,
        "folderName": "One",
        "folderId": 963031296,
        "folderList": [
            {
                "projectId": 0,
                "moduleId": 1,
                "subProjectId": 2,
                "folderName": "Two",
                "folderId": 963031296,
                "id": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "projectId": 0,
        "moduleId": 1,
        "subProjectId": 2,
        "folderName": "Two",
        "folderId": 963031296,
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Prash, I'm afraid you didn't write a question.

Comment: @JánHalaša,edited please advise me on same.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, @Prash
Since you have used a `Set` in a undirectional dependency you must supply an uniqueness of a joined (depended) entities. Any set is using `hashCode()` and `equals()` to determine an availability of the concurent item that is want to be added. Your `FolderData` class doesn't have `hashCode()` and `equals()` so from the point of view of JVM all the deserialized objects are same and because of the `Set` nature it's normal to keep only last example